# Echo return mulitiple variables

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have a problem with an mysql query, I need to extract all data from my table and use him as another sql query.

This is the code I am using:

```
<?php
function toateMhz() {

 require ('SQL.php');
     $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(performanta_cpu) FROM modele ORDER BY CAST(performanta_cpu AS UNSIGNED) DESC";
     foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $linie)  
     {
     $mhz[] = $linie['performanta_cpu'];
     }

     if(isset($mhz['1']))
    {
    $mhz1 = "$mhz[0] OR ";
}    
    else $mhz['0'];

     if(isset($mhz['2']))
    {
    $mhz2 = "$mhz[1] OR ";
}    
    else $mhz['1'];

     if(isset($mhz['3']))
    {
    $mhz3 = "$mhz[2] OR ";
}    
    else $mhz['2'];

     if(isset($mhz['4']))
    {
    $mhz4 = "$mhz[3] OR ";
}    
    else $mhz['3'];

     if(isset($mhz['5']))
    {
    $mhz5 = "$mhz[4] OR ";
}    
    else $mhz['4'];

     if(isset($mhz['6']))
    {
    $mhz6 = "$mhz[5] OR ";
}    
    else $mhz['5'];

     if(isset($mhz['7']))
    {
    $mhz7 = "$mhz[6] OR ";
}    
    else $mhz['6'];

     if(isset($mhz['8']))
    {
    $mhz8 = "$mhz[7] OR ";
}    
    else $mhz['7'];

     if(isset($mhz['9']))
    {
    $mhz9 = "$mhz[8] OR ";
}    
    else $mhz['8'];

     if(isset($mhz['10']))
    {
    $mhz10 = "$mhz[9] OR ";
}    
    else $mhz['9'];

     if(isset($mhz['11']))
    {
    $mhz11 = "$mhz[10] OR ";
}    
    else $mhz['10'];

     if(isset($mhz['12']))
    {
    $mhz12 = "$mhz[11] OR ";
}    
    else $mhz['11'];

     if(isset($mhz['13']))
    {
    $mhz13 = "$mhz[12] OR ";
}    
    else $mhz['12'];

     if(isset($mhz['14']))
    {
    $mhz14 = "$mhz[13] OR ";
}    
    else $mhz['13'];

    if(isset($mhz['15']))
    {
    $mhz14 = "$mhz[14] OR ";
}    
    else $mhz['14'];

    $frecvente = "$mhz1 $mhz2 $mhz3 $mhz4 $mhz5 $mhz6 $mhz7 $mhz8 $mhz9 $mhz10 $mhz11 $mhz12 $mhz13 $mhz14";
    return $frecvente;
}

 echo toateMhz();   
?>
```

And this is the result from code:

`2000 OR 1600 OR 1500 OR 1400 OR 1000 OR 800 OR`

But the correct result is `2000 OR 1600 OR 1500 OR 1400 OR 1000 OR 800 OR 200`

Last word must not be `OR`

Comment: Please take some time to indent your code correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite sure but this might do the trick

```
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $linie) {
    // append value of this record to the array $mhz
    $mhz[] = $linie['performanta_cpu'];
}
// return the concatenation of all elements in $mhz with ' OR ' as "glue" between elements
return join(' OR ', $mhz);
```

`join($s, $arr)` is an alias of [`implode($s, $arr)`](http://docs.php.net/function.implode) which concatenates all (string) elements of the given array $arr and putting $s "between" the elements. E.g.

```
$x = array('a','b', 'c');
echo join(' - ', $x);
```

prints `a - b - c`

Comment: Can you specify what happends with `return join()`?

Comment: `implode` and `join` are aliases. The first parameter (` OR `) is added between each array value, then you don't have to care about the number of values.

Answer (score 2):

Use implode to join your array values into a string :

```
function toateMhz() {

    require ('SQL.php');
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(performanta_cpu) FROM modele ORDER BY CAST(performanta_cpu AS UNSIGNED) DESC";
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $linie)  
    {
        $mhz[] = $linie['performanta_cpu'];
    }
    return implode(" OR ", $mzh);
}
echo toateMhz();
```